# Does ConnectBot supports SSH tunnel /authenticating with pubkey/?

Tags: ssh

Can I connect with ConnectBot to an SSH server to SSH tunnel that doesn't uses passwords, because it's only using "ssh pubkey login"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, ConnectBot supports pubkey authentication and tunnels.